# Smooth Volume Change in java

Tags: java, audio, volume

I want to have a player and an object that emits sounds, and when the player gets closer the volume of the sound increases. My problem is that when I move the player closer and the volume increases, it creates little clicking noises. I think this happens when the volume gets changed too fast but I don't want the player to move really slow.

Here's my code:

```
//Game.al is the player
public void update() {
    if(getVolume() > 0) sound.setVolume(getVolume());
}

public int getVolume() {
    int volume = (int)(100 - ((float)getDistance() / (float)Game.al.listenRadius) * 100);
    return volume;
}

public int getDistance() {
    return (int)(Math.abs(Math.sqrt((x - Game.al.x) * (x - Game.al.x) + (y - Game.al.y) * (y - Game.al.y))));
}
```

Here's the code to change volume: 
(all of the other stuff is so that I can set the volume from 0 - 100 and still being able to hear sound at volume 1)

```
FloatControl gain = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
public void setVolume(float volume) {
    volume /= 2;
    volume += 50;
    volume /= 1.1627f;
    volume -= 80;
    gain.setValue(volume);
}
```

Do I have to use a library?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are not missing the fact that since you have set `FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN`, your `gain.setValue(volume)` will either increase or decrease the current volume by `volume` decibels rather than setting the current volume to `volume` .

You may change the FloatControl type to try which one works best in your situation.

Comment: The `Type.MASTER_GAIN` is the only one that changes the volume to me. The `Type.VOLUME` doesn't work at all.

Comment: I think that the problem is with your setVolume implementation. I suggest you to do a simple linear interpolation representing volume gain as the player approaches target for testing the correctness of FloatControl and post the observations.